# React JS Material UI Dialog Editable Column Save the Change

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid

The sample code for an editable column in MUI dialog does not capture the change to a field.

I took the MUI demo and added an event handler checkChanges() that attempts to capture the change after editing any row data.

The listener does get fired but the data it logs to the console is not the updated data in the UI.

Does this require a commit through state variables? If so, how?

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-g3pmmp?file=/demo.js
```